# How to send a message to a person in my telegram bot?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want to send a text message to a person that is in my telegram bot. I tried to do it with the following code but it didn't work. How do I get this done?

```
bot.SendTextMessage(chat_id,"message");
```

Answer (score 0):

What library are you using? Have you tried [telegram.bot](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot) or [TLSharp](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp)?